# Qt C++: why does ESC not send keyPressEvent if ESC was used to "deselect" a menu?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I'm using Qt 5.6 making a C++ application on a Windows 7 platform.

My class **testMenuBar** has a QMenuBar that simply contains one menu, with one action in said menu.
It also exits when the user inputs the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

The header file is:

```
class testMenuBar : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    testMenuBar(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~testMenuBar();

private:
    QMenu *m_testMenu;
    QAction *m_testAction;

protected:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);
};
```

And the cpp:

```
testMenuBar::testMenuBar(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    m_testAction = new QAction(tr("&TestAct"), this);
    m_testMenu = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&Test"));
    m_testMenu->addAction(m_testAction);
}

testMenuBar::~testMenuBar()
{

}

void testMenuBar::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Escape)
    {
        close();
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I have the menu open, and close it with the ESC key. The ESC key no longer sends a keyPressEvent, thus making the ESC key unable to close the application.

For example:

[image]

If I have selected the menu **Test** as shown above and press ESC to deselect that menu, then <kbd>Esc</kbd> no longer sends the keyPressEvent, hence doesn't quit the application. I pressed the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key **multiple times** and nothing occurs.

So my question is: **why this is happening, and how to fix it?**

Comment: Unrelated: It is unusual for applications to use the `Esc` key for closing the entire application and I would avoid it. See for yourself, try closing common applications you use (e.g., text editor, web browser, etc) with the `Esc` key.

Comment: Maybe it's related to a what has focus. What object has focus when it's working and when it's not working?

Comment: When it works focusWidget() returns me a NULL, and when it doesn't work it returns the QMenuBar.

Comment: How are you calling it? On a `QWidget` or the `QApplication`?

Comment: I used it as: QWidget * fw = focusWidget();

Comment: So that's on a `QWidget` then. Does the one on `QApplication` give the same answer? In any event, I think focus is your issue. Try changing the focus to something other than the menu bar (e.g., clicking the application title bar, clicking somewhere in the window, pressing tab, etc.) and see if it starts working again. **Again**, I state you should not want this behavior anyway.

Comment: I changed the focus according to your examples, but ESC still doesn't give a keyPressEvent (I confirmed the focus changed from QMenuBar to something else). I'm just really confused since other keys give keyPressEvents perfectly fine, but ESC just doesn't when I have the problem.